# Python Standard Library Import Relationships

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio, ironpython, python-module

I am writing an application in C# with VisualStudio and am using IronPython to write some Python scripts for my application. However, it does not have the entire standard library support by default. So to import some modules (such as `os`) I need to point my C# code to where the os module actually is. I also understand that it will still be limited to libraries implemented in pure python.

Ultimately I want to have something that can be installed on another machine. My current workaround is to include a copy of https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/2.7/Lib in the Debug folder where the executable is running and it seems excessive/unnecessary to have to include the entire thing. I tried just placing the files I need (for example `os.py`) here but obviously it imports other modules, which import other modules, etc... I would have to re-run the code to get the error for which module it couldn't find and add them in 1 by 1 and it was getting too tedious.

I was wondering if there was any sort of resource that specifies the relationships between standard library modules and could tell me exactly what files to copy. Essentially what I'm looking for is the graph of the standard library imports. So if I want to `import os` in these scripts I know to copy os.py, ntpath.py, ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably don't need the imports as a tree, but as a simple list, so you can just copy the needed files. You can get that from sys.modules, after you import everything that your script needs - it will contain all modules needed by those that you imported, e.g.:

```
import sys # even if you don't use it - it's a built-in module, won't add a file to the list, needed to get sys.modules
import os
import time
#import whatever-else

# this gives a list of tuples (module,file)
m=[(z,x.__file__) for z,x in sys.modules.items() if hasattr(x,"__file__") ]

for x in m:
   print x[0],x[1]
```